# Android Space on Grid Layout

Tags: java, android

I want to use the Space widget in a Grid Layout:

```
Space space = new Space(this);
Space space2 = new Space(this);

layout3.addView(space);
layout3.addView(space2);
```

The problem is that the boxes are empty so the space are useless, I try to use `onMeasure` method but eclipse say that it is not visible.

Comment: I found a solution to replace the Space, I will use empty textView.